# How to pass a button value to a field

Tags: javascript, html

I need to pass the value of button to the below fields.  That is if I click **PRIVILEGE LEAVE** button the value **PRIVILEGE LEAVE** should be passed to the field **LEAVE TYPE**

```html
<script>
    $.getScript(path + "js/Page4.js");
</script>

<p id="currentPage"> </p>
<div id="but">
    <input type="button" id="compleave" class="appButton" value="PRIVILEGE LEAVE"> <br> <br>
    <input type="button" id="compleave" class="appButton" value="COMPASSIONATE LEAVE"> <br> <br>
    <input type="button" id="searchbutton" class="appButton" value="SICKNESS LEAVE"> <br> <br>
    <input type="button" id="searchbutton" class="appButton" value="Vacation"> <br> <br>
</div>
<div id="show1" style="display:none;">
    <label>LEAVE TYPE: </label> <input type="text" id="ltype" > <br><br>
    <label>START DATE: </label> <input type="text" id="lstrdate"><br><br>
    <label>END DATE: </label> <input type="text" id="lenddate"><br><br>
    <label>LEAVE REASON: </label> <input type="text" id="lreason"><br><br>
    <label>LEAVE DAYS: </label> <input type="text" id="ldays"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="APPLY" id="apply" onclick="funcapply();">
</div>
```

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#compleave').on('click', function(event) {        
        jQuery('#show1').toggle();
        $("#but").remove();
        $("#apply").click(funcapply);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all `id` attribute should be unique on a single HTML page.
In your case `id` `compleave` and `searchbutton` are repeated twice.

To set a value use

```
$('#ltype').val($(this).val());
```

Below is the merged code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#compleave').on('click', function(event) { 

        $('#show1').toggle();
        $("#but").remove();
        $('#ltype').val($(this).val());
        $("#apply").click(funcapply);
    });
});
```

**Update**

To get value of each leave button clicked, change id based event to class i.e. replace `#compleave` with `.appButton`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.appButton').on('click', function(event) { 

        $('#show1').toggle();
        $("#but").remove();
        $('#ltype').val($(this).val());
        $("#apply").click(funcapply);
    });
});
```

Working example in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d61vmpt8/)